# Error in data source: correct iteratively the vector without for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Hello everyone I have a new small problem:
The data I am using have a weird trade time that goes from 17.00 of one day to 16.15 of the day after.
That means that, e.g., for the day 09-27-2013 The source I am using registers the transactions occurred as follows:

```
   DATE   ,  TIME  ,  PRICE
09/27/2013,17:19:42,3225.00,1   #%first obs of the vector
09/27/2013,18:37:59,3225.00,1   #%second obs of the vector
09/27/2013,08:31:32,3200.00,1
09/27/2013,08:36:17,3203.00,1
09/27/2013,09:21:34,3210.50,1   #%fifth obs of the vector
```

Now first and second obs are incorrect for me: they belong to 9/27 trading day but they have been executed on 9/26. Since I am working on some functions in matlab that relies on non-decremental times I need to solve this issue. The date format I am using is actually the datenum Matlab format so I am trying to solve the problem just subtracting one from the incorrect observations:

```
%#Call time the time vector, I can identify the 'incorrect' observations
idx=find(diff(time)<0);
time(idx)=time(idx)-1;
```

It is easy to tell that this will only fix the 'last' incorrect observations of a series. In the previous example this would only correct the second element. And I should run the code several times (I thought about a while loop) until idx will be empty. This is not a big issue when working with small series but I have up to 20millions observations and probably hundred of thousands consecutively incorrect ones.
Is there a way to fix this in a vectorized way?

```
idx=find(diff(time)<0);
while idx
```

However, given that the computation would not be so complex I thought that a for loop could efficiently solve the issue and my idea was the following:

```
[N]=size(time,1);
for i=N:-1:1
  if diff(time(i,:)<0)
     time(i,:)=time(i,:)-1;
  end
end
```

sadly it does not seems to work.
Here is an example of data I am actually using.

```
735504.591157407
735507.708030093      %#  I made this up to give you an example of two consecutively wrong observations
735507.708564815      %#  This is an incorrect observation
735507.160138889
735507.185358796
735507.356562500
```

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensible version -

```
for count = 1:numel(time)
    dtime = diff([0 ;time]);
    ind1 = find(dtime<0,1,'last')-1;
    time(ind1) = time(ind1)-1;
end
```

Faster-but-crazier version -

```
dtime = diff([0 ;time]);
for count = 1:numel(time)
    ind1 = find(dtime<0,1,'last')-1;
    time(ind1) = time(ind1)-1;
    dtime(ind1+1) = 0;
    dtime(ind1) = dtime(ind1)-1; 
end
```

More Crazier version -

```
dtime = diff([0 ;time]);
ind1 = numel(dtime);
for count = 1:numel(time)
    ind1 = find(dtime(1:ind1)<0,1,'last')-1;
    time(ind1) = time(ind1)-1;
    dtime(ind1) = dtime(ind1)-1; 
end
```

Some average computation runtimes for these versions with various datasizes -

```
Datasize 1: 3432 elements
Version 1 - 0.069 sec
Version 2 - 0.042 sec
Version 3 - 0.034 sec

Datasize 2: 20 Million elements
Version 1 - 37029 sec
Version 2 - 23303 sec
Version 3 - 20040 sec
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked as a charm and is not that slow. I just ran it on the 20M observations series.

Comment: Kool! I would be dearly interested in the runtimes for the three versions. Could you post the tic-toc runtimes for them? If not for all three, at least for the last two versions?

Comment: I can actually loop these three tonight and give you the results tomorrow. Anyway, really nice answer, congrats!

Comment: I modified your answer adding computation time for the smallest series I have. As I said, tonight I will run (once) the three codes on the biggest one. I will post the results tomorrow.

Comment: Let me know the runtimes for the biggest one :) I am sort of excited about those!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I had 3 other different problems in the data source that I think could have stucked the routine Divakar proposed. Anyway I thought it was being too slow so I started thinking to another solution and came up with a super quick vectorized one.

Given that the observations I wanted to modify fall in a determined known interval of time the function just look for every observation falling in that interval and modifies it as I want (-1 in my case).

```
function [ datetime ] = correct_date( datetime,starttime, endtime)
%#datetime is my vector of dates and times in matlab numerical format
%#starttime is the starting hour of the interval expressed in datestr format. e.g. '17:00:00'
%#endtime is the ending hour of the interval expressed in datestr format. e.g. '23:59:59'

if (nargin < 1) || (nargin > 3),
    error('Requires 1 to 3 input arguments.')
end
% default values
if nargin == 1,
    starttime='17:00';
    endtime='23:59:59';
elseif nargin == 2,
    endtime='23:59:59';
end

tvec=[datenum(starttime) datenum(endtime)];
tvec=tvec-floor(tvec);    %#As I am working on multiples days I need to isolate only HH:MM:SS for my interval limits
temp=datetime-floor(datetime);         %#same motivation as in the previous line
idx=find(temp>=tvec(1)&temp<=tvec(2)); %#logical find the indices
datetime(idx)=datetime(idx)-1;         %#modify them as I want
clear tvec temp idx
end
```